# ActionBar Sherlock Progressbar not showing on 3.1 but on 4.0+

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-3.0-honeycomb, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

looks like i have a smaller Problem but cant find why.
In my SherlockFragmentActivity onCreate i do the following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

The AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

In an Fragment which loads some Data i do a simple:

```
    getSherlockActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

All working great on ICS, but same code running on my 3.1 Tablet never show an ProgressBar when requested. Anyone can give me an hint why this happen ?

I also have the problem in the Emulator running 2.2, no Progress ever shown. I looked again into **FeatureToggles** from the Sherlock Samples, same code, different result :/

PS: Using 4.01 of ActionBar Sherlock

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you are using the `com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window` import instead of `android.view.Window`.

If you miss this import change the progress method calls will only ever work on ICS and newer devices.

Comment: I wasted over half an hour trying to figure out why two activities with apparently identical code were behaving differently... Fixing the import was what was needed. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, I spent almost 20 mins trying to figure this one out!